# Importing react-native project in android studio

Tags: android-studio, react-native

Am having a small problem with opening/importing a react-native into Android studio.

1. If I open the project using the open a project dialog, it tells me that the project is not gradle enabled and it is such a pain to make and test code changes. Couldn't find out how to enable the project as a gradle project after the fact even after going through the material on the help site.
2. On the other hand, if I import using the import a gradle project dialog and select the build.gradle file, the project is imported, but I only see the files inside the android directory instead of the main project directory. But this method allows me to push changes easily to the emulator.

   How can I fix my problem?

Thanks,

Comment: What folder did you select to open the project with android studio ?  It should be the "android" folder.

Comment: Yes, I used the android folder. I can see everything inside the android folder in the IDE. However, for react-native, looks like the convention is to have the main js files outside the android folder in a separate folder as it is shared between the iOS and Android versions. Hence I would like to be able to edit the js files, but since the folder is outside the Android folder, I can't see it. I have to use a separate editor like Sublime to get to the js files. This is not ideal as I have to keep toggling from Android Studio to Sublime to the emulator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just import **android** directory from Android Studio,
make changes to your **app/build.gradle** 
add these codes before **apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"**

```
project.ext.react = [
        bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
        entryFile: "index.android.js",
        bundleInDebug: false,
        bundleInRelease: true,
        root: "../../",
        jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
        jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
        resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
        resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
        inputExcludes: ["android/", "ios/"],
        nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
        extraPackagerArgs: []
]
```

Now create task for "react-native start" to your gradle

```
task startReactNative(type: Exec) {
    workingDir "../../"
    commandLine  'cmd', '/c', 'react-native', 'start'
    println "Working Directory for React is: $workingDir"
    standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    ext.output = {
        println "React-Native Output: " + standardOutput.toString()
        return standardOutput.toString()
    }
}
```

You can run your app as usual, after app installed to your device, run **startReactNative** task in order to activate Hot Reload